# How To Update Field of a User-Defined Type (UDT) with Spring Data Cassandra CassandraTemplate

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, user-defined-types, spring-data-cassandra

I have a Cassandra table which includes a user-defined type. Using `CassandraTemplate` from Spring Data Cassandra, I want to update a single field of that UDT. This doesn't seem possible.

I have tried this:

```java
database.update(query(
        where("party_id").is(partyId)).and(where("relationship_id").is(relationshipId)),
        update("address.address_line_1", "this field was updated"),
        Address.class);
```

This throws:

```
Query error after 3 ms: UPDATE current_addresses_by_party SET "address.address_line_1"=? WHERE party_id=? AND relationship_id=?;com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Undefined column name "address.address_line_1"
```

Running the CQL given in the error output without the quotes works. I don't know if there's a way to get Spring to execute this statement without putting the column name in quotes.

In a fit of optimism I also tried using the syntax for map types:

```java
database.update(query(
        where("party_id").is(partyId)).and(where("relationship_id").is(relationshipId)),
        Update.empty().set("address").atKey("address_line_1").to("this field was updated"),
        Address.class)
```

This resulted in the error you would expect: the field is not a map.

Is there a way to do what I want with `CassandraTemplate` without resorting to direct CQL? If `CassandraTemplate` lacks this feature, it would be great if the devs added it.

I was surprised that I couldn't find anyone else wanting to do this. Maybe I'm doing something completely wrong? I'm fairly new to Cassandra.